# need to use web application as publisher and console application as consumer for rabbit mq

Tags: rabbitmq

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<DataTable>

  <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">

    <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:MainDataTable="point24" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">

      <xs:complexType>

        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">

          <xs:element name="point24">

            <xs:complexType>

              <xs:sequence>

                <xs:element name="RoadCode" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />

                <xs:element name="Chainage" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />

                <xs:element name="Dir" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />

                <xs:element name="Latitude" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />

                <xs:element name="Longitude" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />

                <xs:element name="test1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />

                <xs:element name="CompositeKey" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />

                <xs:element name="AddedBy" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />

                <xs:element name="AddedOn" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />

                <xs:element name="ModifiedBy" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />

                <xs:element name="ModifiedOn" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />

                <xs:element name="MasterColumnKey" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />

                <xs:element name="LinkCode" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />

                <xs:element name="SurveyId" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />

              </xs:sequence>

            </xs:complexType>

          </xs:element>

        </xs:choice>

      </xs:complexType>

    </xs:element>

  </xs:schema>

  <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">

    <DocumentElement>

      <point24 diffgr:id="point241" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">

        <RoadCode>SH0008</RoadCode>

        <Chainage>5894</Chainage>

        <Dir>I</Dir>

        <Latitude>6.3</Latitude>

        <Longitude>2.5</Longitude>

        <test1>56</test1>

        <CompositeKey>SH00085894IJAN2016</CompositeKey>

        <AddedBy>dev</AddedBy>

        <AddedOn>2017-11-29T10:16:09.3488278+05:30</AddedOn>

        <MasterColumnKey>SH0008589456JAN2016</MasterColumnKey>

        <LinkCode>LI:SH00084502</LinkCode>

        <SurveyId>JAN2016</SurveyId>

      </point24>

    </DocumentElement>

  </diffgr:diffgram>

</DataTable>
```

Am publishing a datatable into queue using rabbit mq and trying to consume the datable from console application.
Unable to get the data.

I am using rabbit mq 3.6.14 version with erlang 20.1[Rabbit MQ management UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMB4w.png)

Am adding the datatable to queue from web application like this..
 [Producer web application code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNNI1.png)

Am retreiving the message from queue from console application 
[Consumer application code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djxxY.png)

here is my queue binding
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycU1a.png)

[Queue Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrFPt.png)
[Binding Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXoSC.png)
please suggest.

Comment: Hello,

Welcome so SO, please tell us a bit more about your stuff:

 - Version of softwares
 - Screenshot of rabbitMQ ui (to see the queue state at least)
 - Queue configuration (mode / binds ...)

Comment: Hi Thomas, i have added the version and screen shot of management UI

Comment: How your queue is configured ? do you understand what is an exchange / routingKey / bind?

Comment: var factory = new ConnectionFactory();
          
            factory.HostName = HostName;
            Connection = factory.CreateConnection();
            Channel = Connection.CreateModel();
            Channel.ExchangeDeclare(ExchangeName, ExchangeTypeVal, false, false, null);
            Channel.QueueDeclare(QueueName,false,false,false,null);
            Channel.QueueBind(QueueName, ExchangeName, RoutingKey, null);

Comment: Please post a RabbitMQ web UI screenshot of the queue details.

Comment: Message in the queue is in xml format

Comment: Added queue and binding screenshots

Comment: How is built your channel variable ? (here you must declare the queue) or use exchange.

Comment: do i need to declare exchange and bind it to the queue in consumer application also

Comment: Yes ! on your app, you must declare a queue or an exchange+routingKey

Comment: Tried using exchange and routing key in consumer but no luck.

Comment: the connection was given in USING STATEMENT.                                 
        using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
        {} so  it was closed immediately after consume i was not getting data. Now i removed them and it is working fine. Thank you